# Error opening a file with h5fopen_f in FORTRAN / MPI / HDF5 ( 1.10.1 )

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, hdf5

I am using a Fortran code that uses HDF5 (1.**10**.1). At some point there is a call to open a file using `h5fopen_f`:

```
H5FileName = "+hdf5/Temperature_00000_00001.h5"
CALL h5fopen_f(H5FileName, H5F_ACC_RDWR_F, file, hdferr)
Scalardataset = 'Temperature_00001_0000'
call h5ltget_dataset_info_f(file, Scalardataset, dimstmp, type_class, type_size, hdferr)
call h5fclose_f(file,hdferr)
```

which is giving me an error:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.1) MPI-process 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 586 in H5Fopen(): unable to open file
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #001: H5Fint.c line 1305 in H5F_open(): unable to lock the file
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #002: H5FD.c line 1839 in H5FD_lock(): driver lock request failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Can't update object
  #003: H5FDsec2.c line 940 in H5FD_sec2_lock(): unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Bad file ID accessed
```

I have checked that the file exists, it's where it should and that I have the right permissions. Also, the code works fine when I just use one process, and when I use more than one, one of the processes is able to open the file ( `err=0` ), but the rest can't ( `err=-1` ). Finally, I have this same code installed somewhere else and it works just fine (with version 1.**8**.14).

Can this be a problem with the version?

Comment: Does this file really exist? Is the path correct? Pleas supply a [mcve].

Comment: It looks like you're trying to lock the fine *and* open it on multiple processes at the same time. But, as @VladimirF says, we need to see the code.

Comment: @VladimirF, @Ross. I have edited the original post to include a snippet of the code. Sorry about that.
As I mentioned, the file exists and the path is right
I have managed to solve it by opening it as read only, using `H5F_ACC_RDONLY_F` instead of `H5F_ACC_RDWR_F`. But I did not need to do this when I use version 1.8.14. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Similar problem here via python and 1.10.1: Unable to open/create file '/Users/klay6683/local_data/2017-12-31_planet_four_classifications_queryable.h5'
[0:apply]: OSError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5F.c", line 586, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1305, in H5F_open
    unable to lock the file
  File "H5FD.c", line 1839, in H5FD_lock
    driver lock request failed
  File "H5FDsec2.c", line 940, in H5FD_sec2_lock
    unable to lock file, errno = 35, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
End of HDF5 error back trace.
HDF5 1.8.18 runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways of fixing this:

- Opening the files as read only, using `H5F_ACC_RDONLY_F` instead of `H5F_ACC_RDWR_F` (this is fine for me because I don't need to write.
- Recompiling everything using `HDF5 1.8.14`. I guess that read and write permissions are more restrictive in version 1.10.x than in version 1.8.x.

Ideally I would like to be able to use a more up to date version of `HDF5` together with `H5F_ACC_RDWR_F`, but for now it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue with HDF5 1.10.1.  We are using multiple readers to access a file in H5F_ACC_RDONLY mode.

Disabling file locking by setting the environment variable seems to resolve the `H5FDsec2.c line 940 in H5FD_sec2_lock(): unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable'`:

```
export HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING="FALSE"
```

This env var is checked at runtime by hdf5.  See:   https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/RELEASE.txt​